# IOS 10 Speech Recognition API : Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1101

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, ios10

I try using speech recognition as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   [self startRecognizer];
}

- (void)startRecognizer {

   [SFSpeechRecognizer requestAuthorization:^(SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus status) {
      if (status == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
      {
        SFSpeechRecognizer *sf =[[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] init];
        NSURL *mp3Path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp3"];
        SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest *speechRequest = [[SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest alloc]initWithURL:mp3Path];
        [sf recognitionTaskWithRequest:speechRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSString * translatedString = [[[result bestTranscription] formattedString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

            NSLog(@"%@",translatedString);
        }];
      }
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist` and run this project in device if you are testing in `simulator`. You need ios real device running `ios10` to test this!

You can refer [hackingwithswift's arcticle](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios10) for more details!

Comment: In my case I was stopping audioEngine without checking it is currently running or not. I just fixed with this code: if self.audioEngine.isRunning { self.audioEngine.stop() self.recognitionRequest?.endAudio() }